# i get a bus error and code stops working by itself after 3 inputs

Tags: c, bus-error

I got 2 issues with this code?
first is that it stops by itself after 3 different inputs of students and when i want the to print out all the students that passed it gives me zsh bus error?

[image: zsh bus error]

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>

struct student
{
    int no;
    char name[20];
    int studentnumber;
    int points;
    int b;
};

void passed(struct student st[], int b, int p)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)
    {
        if (st[j].points >= b)
        {
            printf("%s passed\n", st[j].name);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, b, e;
    int p = 1;

    struct student st[p];
    printf("insert data %d of participant:", p);

    for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
        printf("\nName studentnumber points eingeben:");
        scanf("%s %d %d", st[i].name, &st[i].studentnumber, &st[i].points);

        printf("Would you like to instert another participant? 0 yds 1 no\n");
        scanf("%d", &e);
        if (e == 0)
        {
            p++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Points to pass:");
            scanf("%d", &b);
            passed(st, b, p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Memory corruption. Apply [`valgrind`](https://valgrind.org).

Comment: FYI, "zsh: bus error ./pg2" means that zsh is telling you that *./pg2* got a bus error. There's no problem with zsh itself.

Comment: When you `p++`, that does not cause `st` to resize. It is the size it had at the point it was created (when `p` was `1`).

Answer (score 1):

```
int p = 1;
struct student st[p];
```

This defines an array of `p` elements, using the value `p` has *right then*, which is 1. Later, when you increment `p`, the size of the array **does not change**. Thus, on the second and subsequent iterations of the loop, you write past the end of the array and the program malfunctions.

Dynamically resizable arrays have to be implemented by hand in C, using `realloc`.

Comment: could you show me how i could implement it with realloc, ive never heard of it and idk how to use it im completly new to this

Comment: @gem Sorry, too long for the answer box, but if you search "dynamic resize array realloc" some tutorials should come up.